# Convert clockface timepicker to Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

As there is no good plugin in angularjs for time-picker(don't like angularUI Bootstrap timepicker for some reason), I was looking for a way to convert existing [jquery clockface interface plugin](http://vitalets.github.io/clockface/) to angularjs.

Tried converting it myself, but it did n't work. Model is not updated when I select time.

```
.directive('clockface_1', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',

                    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                        $(function () {
                            $('.clockface_1').clockface();
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text"  data-format="HH:mm"
                               class="form-control clockface_1" clockface_1=""/>
```

**UPD**:
By learning a little bit angularJS directive, I was able to implement it:
Following worked for me:

```
.directive('clockface', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require : 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                    element.clockface({
                        format: 'HH:mm'
                    }).on('pick.clockface', function(e, data) {
                        var hr=data.hour?("0" +data.hour).slice (-2):'00';
                        var mn=data.minute?("0" +data.minute).slice (-2):'00';
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(hr+':'+mn);
                        scope.$apply();
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text"  data-format="HH:mm"
                               class="form-control clockface" clockface ng-model="to_time"/>
```

Only problem this solution has, the time picker is not hidden on input blur.

How to hide clockface on blur? 
Also, one another problem that I faced is, whenever I attach this plugin to modal, and after modal opens, I clicked on text box after which the clockface appears. If I close the modal, then clockface still keeps hanging on body element.

Comment: just like any code outside of angular you need to use `$apply()` within event handler to update scope

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested, but try this:

```
.directive('ngClockface', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                            $(element).clockface();
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```